# Remove .php extension only in certain directory - web.config

Tags: iis, web-server, regex, web.config

I'm having trouble making the pattern for matching the urls in a certain directory.
I want to redirect users from mysite.com/posts/some-post.php to mysite.com/posts/some-post meaning that I want to remove the .php extension, but only in that directory, because I have already tried the universal rule  which breaks my download urls which don't end with a .php extension

Here's the code that I'm currently using and which **DOES NOT WORK**

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^posts/([a-z0-9-])$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but I think you need to take the .php out of the action line?  This reads that you find a file with the .php, pull out REQUEST and then put .php right back onto it.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm new with the whole URL rewrite thing and I haven't really found any resources about it. I've edited what you suggested, still no luck, but thank you, anyway.

Comment: Ah, yeah, read too fast - that's what the server is doing, but apparently that is not what is seen.

Comment: Here we go, seems this is a solvable problem, but a tiny bit gnarly at it:  https://www.saotn.org/iis-url-rewrite-hide-php-extension/ (posted the information from it but it disappeared, probably special character unhappiness, sorry, you'll have to go to the site to see what they did).

Comment: @Mary Oh, Mary, you're a life-saver! If I knew you I would buy a chocolate, thank you very much, this works great!

Comment: @Mary - or you could put that in an answer and user301299 could accept it. In this way both of you will be helping others. (Comments aren't really made for answering)